Transform the value of column to number of rows
I m new in R.
I want to transform the column value to number of rows.
data:
Month         Number
March         1
February      2
February      2

The output i want is :
Month         Number
March         1
February      1
February      1
February      1
February      1

I try this code but he give me this
data %>%
    ungroup %>%
    uncount(Number)


In base R:
data.frame(Month = rep(df$Month, df$Number), Number = 1L)

With dplyr:
reframe(df, Month = rep(Month, Number), Number = 1L)

Input data (in reproducible form)
df <- data.frame(
  Month = c("March", "February", "February"), Number = c(1L, 2L, 2L)
)

